# Determining the primitive ideal space of C-star algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Is there a general way of finding a primitive ideal space of $C^*$-algebra?

For example, if $C^*$-algebra is given by the universal $C^*$-algebra generated by two self-adjoint unitary elements, how does one determine its primitive ideal space?

What is a general (or best) apprach to finding its primitive ideal space of a $C^*$-algebra?

Comment: The example you consider is very special, as it is the $C^*$-algebra of the infinite dihedral group, which is notoriously type I. The spectrum in that case is "an interval with 2+2 endpoints", i.e. the union of two closed intervals identified along their interiors. This well-known fact can be found e.g. in these notes by I. Putnam: http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/t/Math_533_Lecture_Notes.pdf

Comment: Your general question seems too optimistic and open-ended, although as @AlainValette has pointed out one can do quite a lot for Type I groups. You will have problems if your Cstar algebra is not "postliminal", a term which is explained and studied in e.g. Dixmier's book.

Comment: sometimes the following fact is useful: If $I$ is a closed ideal in a $C^*$-algebra $A$, it is $$\hat{A}=\hat{A}_I\coprod \hat{A}_{A/I}=\widehat{I}\coprod  \widehat{A/I},$$ where $\hat{A}_I=\{[\pi]\in \hat{A}: \pi(I)\neq 0\}$ and $\hat{A}_{A/I}=\{[\pi]\in \hat{A}: \pi(I)=0\}$. I used it in this http://mathoverflow.net/questions/219419/what-is-hata-pi-pi-is-a-irreducible-representation-of-a-a-is-a case. But as the others said, your question is too open ended.

Comment: Just to update the link in Alain's comment: http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/putnam/ln/lecture_notes.html